# Почему CURL не хочет загружать Composer?

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl, composer

Возникал проблема при установке composer-a, никак не хочет устанавливаться. Все зависимости установил. Пытался и глобально поставить и в проект, но получается вот такая проблемкка.

```
kornell@kornell-virtual-machine:~$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
All settings correct for using Composer
kornell@kornell-virtual-machine:~$ sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
All settings correct for using Composer
kornell@kornell-virtual-machine:~$
```

Самой загрузки не происходит, а только All settings correct for using Composer и всё. Ошибок никаких не выдает.

Система Ubuntu 14.04

Стоит на виртуальной машине.

Увеличил немного оперативную память, так как до этого была ошибка "Ошибка сегментирования (сделан дамп памяти)"

Куда копать, кто подскажет?

Comment: А почему вы решили, что загрузка не происходит? Вы пробовали выполнить curl отдельно? Что происходит? Пробовали указать другой каталог в `install-dir`?

Comment: Пробовал выполнять отдельно, такой же результат.
root@kornell-virtual-machine:/var/www# curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php
All settings correct for using Composer
root@kornell-virtual-machine:/var/www# exit
exit
kornell@kornell-virtual-machine:~$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php

All settings correct for using Composer
kornell@kornell-virtual-machine:~$ 
После запроса смотрел, не создаёт ничего.